# How to append list to gridview?

Tags: c#

I have following code to set List to datasource.

```
gridControl1.datasource = employeeList; //employeeList is list of employee
```

how can I append another list to gridControl1?

Comment: Append your list to employeeList.

Comment: employeeList update everytime when timer.tick call. It will not be same.

Comment: You were not mentioning anything regarding timer in the question.please update the question in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't append them to the grid control but to the list to which the grid is bound - append them to the employeeList and they then be in the controls datasource.

Comment: I am doing the same now. But that will refresh whole gridview every time when I append row.